# Czech characters in console output

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

I am having a set of possible characters of czech alphabet:

```
String a = "áčďéěíňóřšťúůýžÁČĎÉĚÍŇÓŘŠŤÚŮÝŽ";
```

And I am trying to print it to the Java console. I googled here and there, however, no matter what approach and encoding I have tried so far, I am unable to print some of them not being replaced with some corrupted characters.

The best what I could achieved so far is to wrap `System.out` with `PrintWriter` with custom encoding:

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, encoding);
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(osw);
```

But I can't figure out the correct one. The best result I had with `Cp1250`, but still far from being perfect. The output is:

```
áèïéìíòóøš�úùýžÁÈÏÉÌÍÒÓØŠ�ÚÙÝŽ
```

I also tried numerous ways to convert the original string via getBytes

```
String newString = new String(originalString.getBytes(encoding1), encoding2);
```

But that also didn't lead me to any success so far.

Last of my ideas was to convert into Unicode values, which would be:

```
"\u00E1\u010D\u010F\u00E9\u011B\u00ED\u0148\u00F3\u0159\u0161\u0165\u00FA\u016F\u00FD\u017E\u00C1\u010C\u010E\u00C9\u011A\u00CD\u0147\u00D3\u0158\u0160\u0164\u00DA\u016E\u00DD\u017D"
```

But the output then still doesn't seem okay...

So asking here for some hint seems like my last resort. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What is your OS, and what is its default console encoding? (e.g. for Windows, what is the output of `chcp`?)

Comment: I am running on Windows 10 Enterprise. And chcp returned 437.

Comment: Try chcp 65001 before running your Java application.

Comment: Hm. `chcp 65001` + wrapping `System.out` as `UTF8` works. Also with `chcp 852` native `System.out` works correctly. So thanks a lot for good hint and for partial solution. However, I would have thought there must be some portable solution not being platform (and even environment) dependant?

Comment: Use AWT or Swing. For console output, there is no way for Java to know what character set is supported by your terminal.

Comment: Your output is a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) of the following kind: `"áčďéěíňóřšťúůýžÁČĎÉĚÍŇÓŘŠŤÚŮÝŽ".encode( 'cp1250').decode( 'cp1252','replace')` returns `áèïéìíòóøš�úùýžÁÈÏÉÌÍÒÓØŠ�ÚÙÝŽ` (sorry, I don't speak Java so example given in Python).